# Как в авторизации открыть модальное окно с ошибкой когда пароль неверный?

Tags: php

```
<?php
include 'functions.php'; 
$auth = false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $login = trim($_POST['login']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $auth = authorization($login, $password);
    if($auth === true){
        header("Location: ../");    
    }
}
if($auth !== true){
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Авторизация</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">      
    </head>
<html>  
    <body>
    <form name="login" action="" method="POST"> 
        <div class="login">
        <div class="top"><h1 class="toptext">ВХОД</h1></div>
            <a class="apass">...?</a>
            <div class="regbut"><input type="submit" name="button" value="Регистрация"></div><br>
            <div class="logininput_login"><label>ИМЯ:</label> <input type="text" name="login"></div><br>
            <div class="logininput_password"><label>ПАРОЛЬ:</label> <input type="password" name="password"></div><br>
            <div class="login_but"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти"></div>  
        </div>
    </form>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            include "connect.php";
            $login = ($_POST['login']);
            $password = ($_POST['password']);   
                        $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `password`='".$password."'");
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){   
                            echo '<a href="#openModal">Открыть модаль</a>        
                            <div id="openModal" class="modal">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                            <h3 class="modal-title">Пароль неверный</h3>
                            </div>   
                            <div class="buton_modal">
                            <a href="#close" class="modala"><input type="submit" name="button" value="ОК"></a>
                            </div>      
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>';
                        }
                    }
                }       
        ?>
<script src="modal.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Опишите более детально вашу проблему и как вы ее пытались решить, с чем столкнулись. Никто не будет вот так решать вашу проблему с вашим кодом

Answer (score 0):

на JavaScript написать условие, где выводится alert. 
Допустим: if (Условие) {
        echo 'alert("Сообщение");';

Comment: Вы не так поняли, есть модальное окно, но его можно открыть только при нажатии на линк <a href="#openModal"></a>, нужно чтобы модальное окно открывалось само при проверке пароля.

Answer (score 0):

header('Location: #openModal');